# Makefile for building ASM/C project

Tags: c, makefile

I am building a bare bones freestanding kernel in ASM and C. My make file is below.

```
CFLAGS= -ffreestanding -nostdlib -gdwarf-4 -m32 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11
ASMCFLAGS= -f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all
LDFLAGS= --nmagic -m elf_i386 --script=os.lds

BUILD_DIR=../build/os
BUILD_DIR_IMM=$(BUILD_DIR)/imm
BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM=$(BUILD_DIR_IMM)/asm
BUILD_DIR_IMM_C=$(BUILD_DIR_IMM)/c
BUILD_OUTPUT=$(BUILD_DIR)/os

OS_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OS_C_OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, $(BUILD_DIR_IMM_C)/%.o, $(OS_C_SRCS))

OS_ASM_SRCS := $(wildcard *.asm)
OS_ASM_OBJS := $(patsubst %.asm, $(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/%.o, $(OS_ASM_SRCS))

OS_SRCS := $(OS_C_SRCS) $(OS_ASM_SRCS)
OS_OBJS := $(OS_ASM_OBJS) $(OS_C_OBJS)

all: $(BUILD_OUTPUT)

prepdir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_IMM_C)
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)

$(OS_C_OBJS): $(OS_C_SRCS) $(OS_ASM_OBJS) prepdir
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/__init.o: __init.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) __init.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/kinit.o: kinit.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) kinit.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/keyboard.o: keyboard.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) keyboard.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/interrupt.o: interrupt.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) interrupt.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/string.o: string.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) string.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR_IMM_ASM)/vid.o: vid.asm prepdir
    nasm $(ASMCFLAGS) vid.asm -o $@

$(BUILD_OUTPUT): $(OS_C_OBJS) $(OS_ASM_OBJS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OS_OBJS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

This makefile is used as a child makefile.

My primary concern is that I cannot pass multiple files to NASM, so I need a rule for each assembly file I have. My secondary concern is cross dependencies on other files, for instance, my C files should be rebuild if any C header files change.

Answer (score 5):

I see a number of things that may help you improve this.

### Don't manually write a `Makefile`

Since you're using standard tools such as `gcc` and `ld`, you could use: `autotools` (that is the collection of [`autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) and [related software](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html#family)) instead of writing and maintaining your own `Makefile`.  There is a learning curve, of course, but the benefits are considerable, especially if you're writing software that will become open source.  To do that here, you can start with these two files:

#### configure.ac

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([foo.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_PROG_CC

PACKAGE_CFLAGS="-ffreestanding -nostdlib -gdwarf-4 -m32 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11"
PACKAGE_LDFLAGS="--nmagic -m elf_i386 --script=os.lds"
PACKAGE_NASMFLAGS="-f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all"

AC_SUBST([PACKAGE_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([PACKAGE_LDFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([PACKAGE_NASMFLAGS])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(foreign)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

#### Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = os
os_SOURCES = foo.c ${asm_sources}
os_NASMFLAGS = @PACKAGE_NASMFLAGS@
os_LDFLAGS = @PACKAGE_LDFLAGS@
AM_CPPFLAGS = @PACKAGE_CFLAGS@
NASM = /usr/bin/nasm

asm_sources = thing1.asm thing2.asm

.asm.o:
        $(NASM) $(os_NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

With these, you can execute `autoreconf -i` in the same directory.  Next, create a build directory anywhere (one of the advantages of `automake`) and execute the generated `configure` file from that directory.  That will create a nice `Makefile` for you which you can then execute in the usual way by typing `make`.

Another tool I use very often is [`CMake`](https://cmake.org/), which does something similar to `autotools` in that it creates build scripts for you, but it's not tied to Linux and BSD and can work with Windows-based compilers as well.

With that said, if you're *determined* to do it the hard way, there are some things you can improve in your existing file.

### Define an implicit rule

GNU Make (which I assume that you're using) knows how to create object files from assembly files, but only by using `as` rather than `nasm`.  It's very simple to teach it a new trick, however, by defining an **implicit rule**.  Here's one:

```
.asm.o:
        $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This is a simple rule that tells `make` that the "recipe" to create a `.o` file from a `.asm` file is to run the command listed below.  That way you only need to list a dependency and not the rule each time.  That is:

```
thing1.o: thing1.asm
```

However, even this is often not necessary if you've defined the implicit rule.  The next suggestion explains.

### Make `make` work harder

The purpose to having `make` is to offload some of the work of the programmer to quickly do only what's necessary to rebuild a new binary.  You can make it work harder than you currently are, while making things easier to maintain and a bit shorter as well.  If you're using GNU Make, you can define an implicit rule like this (note the slightly different syntax from the standard implicit rule listed above):

```
%.o : %.asm
        $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Then simply tell `make` the object files needed and let it figure out by itself that it needs to run the compiler on C files and `nasm` on assembly files:

```
os : foo.o thing1.o thing2.o
        ld $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

### Don't include paths in filenames

Inserting and maintaining paths everywhere is tedious and error prone.  Better is to use `VPATH` within the `Makefile` like this:

```
VPATH=../src
```

Now assuming your directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── build
└── src
```

You can navigate into the empty `build` directory and type `make -f ../src/Makefile`.  All of the binaries will be created in the `build` directory and the source directory will be untounched.  `VPATH` tells make where to look for sources it needs.  This is a much nicer way to do things.

### Mark phony targets `.PHONY`

There isn't really an `all` file created and there really isn't a `clean` file.  These are actually just tags that identify a target whose rules should always be run.  For this reason they should be explicitly declared as phony:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf os $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

### Explicitly name sources

Lines like this one:

```
OS_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
```

generally should be avoided.  The reason is that if you create, say, a small test file to try out a concept while working on the source and then forget to delete it, it becomes part of the build *whether you wanted it or not.*  It's usually far better to explicitly name files rather than using wildcards.

### Putting it all together

Here's a revised `Makefile` which implements these suggestions:

#### Makefile

```
CFLAGS= -ffreestanding -nostdlib -gdwarf-4 -m32 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11
NASM=nasm
NASMFLAGS= -f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all
LDFLAGS= --nmagic -m elf_i386 -L$(VPATH) --script=os.lds
VPATH=../src
OBJECT_FILES=foo.o thing1.o thing2.o

.PHONY: all
all: os

%.o : %.asm
        $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $< -o $@

os : foo.o thing1.o thing2.o
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf os $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

### Create libraries

One thing I forgot to mention was that it's often good practice to create libraries.  By grouping related object code together into a library, you gain a number of advantages.  First, recompiling the project typically becomes a bit faster.  Second, it allows (forces?) you to think carefully about the interface.  A well-defined interface to library code not only makes it easier to use (and potentially replace with an improved or alternate version) but also aids in testing.  Third, by having a separate library, testing can often be simplified by writing tests that thoroughly exercise each library.  When all libraries are tested, it's easier to test the main application with confidence.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Wouldn't autoconfig require me to re-execute it everytime I add a new source file to the project?  Secondly, it appears your makefile does not output files to a `build` folder, am I right?

Comment: Actually, the makefile created via autotools will automatically take care of rerunning `configure` without any further intervention.  That is, after you've built it once, you could simply add "thing3.asm" to `Makefile.am` and all the other steps would automatically happen.

Comment: Also, if you do it the way I suggest, by navigating into a build directory and executing `configure` from there, any generated files will be created there (including `.o` or `.so` and the final linked target binary) and *only* there, leaving your source tree untouched.  This allows, among many other advantages, building from source code on non-writable media (e.g. CD or DVD).

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I have a slightly [larger build](https://github.com/sebazzz/sdos). I have a bootloader which is outputted to build/bootloader, and the kernel which is emitted to build/os, which is then put on a disk image emitted in `build/disk.img`. Also a lot of open source projects actually place ./configure in the root of the project and you can execute it there, am I right?

Comment: Yes the `configure` script is most often placed in the root directory of a project and checked in to the repository.  The reason is that while anyone *could* regenerate it, providing it in the repo means that *users* of the project (as contrasted with *developers*) only need a toolchain (compiler, linker, etc.) and don't need autotools.  An example that doesn't do that: https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin